# Given a sequence and find the smallest natural number s.t.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question itself comes from a daily life problem which I think could take a large wall of text to explain. Unfortunately, I don't have any clue about this question and I'm also not sure how to search for it.

Q: Given a sequence $A$ of $N$ unique items and an arbitrary natural number $c$ such that $c \le N$, find the smallest natural number $k$ such that:

There exists $k$ sequences $S_1, S_2, \dotsc, S_k$, where each $S_i$ consists of items from sequence $A$. When arbitrary $c$ items are chosen without duplicates from $A$ to form a set $D$, let the first item from $S_i$ that $D$ contains to be $SD_i$ (there could also be no such item, and in that case, $SD_i$ is ignored), and the set of all $SD_i$ to be $SD$. Then we need to have $D = SD$.

Could $k$ be as small as $c$? Or there only exists a trivial solution that $k = N$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We *like* walls of text! We call them "context" and they let us see that you've put some thought into the matter before coming and asking us.